iPadOS 18 TabView covers NavigationSplitView Toolbar Items
I updated my App to iOS and iPadOS 18.
The app uses the TabBar, which was previously at the bottom of the screen, and a NavigationSplitView in one tab.
The new TabBar is at the top and covers my toolbar buttons.
It seems as if the joint use of TabBar and NavigationSplitView is not wanted. Is there an alternative?
The problem can be reproduced with this swiftui code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .A
    
    enum Tab {
        case A
        case B
        case C
        case D
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            NavigationSplitView {
                Text("Sidebar")
            } content: {
                Text("Content")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                            Button("Covered") {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } detail: {
                Text("Detail")
            }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab A", systemImage: "circle")
                }
                .tag(Tab.A)
                .navigationTitle("Shops")
            Text("B")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab B", systemImage: "square")
                }
                .tag(Tab.B)
            Text("C")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab C", systemImage: "triangle")
                }
                .tag(Tab.C)
            Text("D")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab C", systemImage: "diamond")
                }
                .tag(Tab.C)
        }
    }
}

The "Covered" Button cannot be seen because it is behind the tabbar.

This could be a new feature of iPad ios18, from the release-notes
"On iPad, TabViews using the automatic style have a new appearance in the regular horizontal size class. The tab bar now appears at the top, instead of the bottom, with a more compact visual appearance. (117029720)"

This is a new feature. However this feature destroys my layout and it seems like there is no way to go back to the old tabbar style.
